# Xamarin Forms breakpoints not working in visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am new in Xamarin Forms. I create a portable project and run it with out problem. But in App class (portable) or MainActivity OnCreate method in Android project breakpoints not hitting. 
Also Xamarin for visual studio is "Stable".

What is problem?
Does Xamarin Forms (portable) support breakpoints for debug?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when source code folder path consist "@", break points not working. I moved project folder from @Project to another folder without @ and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
Right click on your Android project -> Properties -> Build -> Uncheck "Optimize Code".
```

And

```
Android project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Debugging information -> set it to "Full".
```